# What the best strategy to test Craft template?

Tags: templating, tests

I would like to know if there is a way unit test templates using Craft 2.5? For example trying to prevent null pointers happening in production when an image is remove from the entry

Comment: I'm not sure how you would unit test templates, probably it could be done, but you might be better served by coding defensively, as per [Handling Errors Gracefully in Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/handling-errors-gracefully-in-craft-cms#what-it-means-to-code-defensively)

Comment: I'll second [Andrew's](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/28564/what-the-best-strategy-to-test-craft-template#comment37158_28564) suggestion as a better approach.  Outside of that, the front-end templates of a site are generally tested with acceptance or integration testing instead of unit testing.